# Redux: what about performances if each state change is a new object?

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, redux

In the Redux documentation, in the [chapter about `Reducer`s](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), is stated this:

> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign().
>   Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter }) is also
>   wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty
>   object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread
>   operator proposal to write { ...state, ...newState } instead.

My question is: does this creation of new `State` objects have any impact on performance and memory consumption?

If I create each time a new object, then I have in memory many many `State` objects and this should occupy a lot of memory in the long run.

How does is this handled? What am I missing about performance issues and memory consumption?

Comment: there are nice answers [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304577/284657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in a word... not really.

If your state object is the only one with a reference to that object, and it should be, then when you replace that object with another, the older object will be cleaned up.  See this link about memory and garbage collection in Javascript:

https://codeburst.io/javascript-memory-management-and-garbage-collection-in-javascript-ebe7a97d7143

You may think that your component is storing references to the state (it shouldn't), but usually these are just temporary references to state parts passed into the render method.

Comment: Yes, thinking better at the question, I arrived at the same conclusion: in the end the reference is always one... Thank you for your answer!